# Defining whats in a tab when clicking on one

Tags: html, tabs

Ive researched about , and am having an extremely hard time trying to figure this one out (noob html coder here)

so far ive come about using a data toggle for the tabs, but how i would incoporate the data into one tab is still confusing for me,

in the code below everything from "greetings" to "heres my facebook" has to go into all about me

then under "My businesses" i'll put other things

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<style>
#header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
}

#nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:1024px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;              

}
#section {
    width:700px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;        
}
#footer {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
   padding:5px;      
}

#linespacing1 {
text-align:500px;

}

</style>
</head>

<div id="header">
<h1>Kulkarni Industries (K.I)</h1>
</div>

<div id="nav">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
<div id="linespacing1">
  <ul class="list-inline">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-left:0px;">
   <li class="active"> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">All about me</a> </li>
   <li class="active"> <a data-toggle="tab" href="menu2">My Businesses</a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>



    <p>
    <div style="text-align:center;margin-left:-50px;">

    Greetings!

</div>
    </p>



<div style="text-align:center; margin-left:-50px;">

<h1>A little information about me </h1>


    <p>

    Welcome to my world ;D

    </p>


    <p>

    Let me tell you a little about myself

    </p>
    <p>
    Heres a photo of me
    </p>

    <p>

    <body>

    <a href="https://www.facebook.com"> 

    <img src=file:///C:/Users/shank/Pictures/S5%20Photos/DCIM/Camera/Snapchat-7079236859296311049.jpg Width="200" height="300" />

    </a>    

    <p>

      Click on it and youll go to my Facebook
    </body>
    </p>

<div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>to .</p>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add a working example in CodePen or JSFiddle as a starting point for your question. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this (using your code-slightly modified). Basically with the tabs - you put all content that you want into tab panes that have the id that you have listed as the href in the tab navigation menu. Note the use of "#" in the tab nav menu which targets the tab pane with that id. All tab panes are wrapped in a tab content div and the active tab navigation and active tab pane are given a class of "active".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<style>
#header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
}

#nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:1024px;
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;              

}
#section {
    width:700px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;        
}
#footer {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
   padding:5px;      
}

#linespacing1 {
text-align:500px;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <nav>
        <h1>Kulkarni Industries (K.I)</h1>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">All about me</a> </li>
        <li> <a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">My Businesses</a> </li>
    </ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active " id="menu1" style="padding:15px">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <p>Greetings!</p>
            <h1>A little information about me </h1>
            <p>Welcome to my world ;D</p>
            <p>Let me tell you a little about myself</p>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <p>Heres a photo of me</p>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com"> 
                <img src="file:///C:/Users/shank/Pictures/S5%20Photos/DCIM/Camera/Snapchat-7079236859296311049.jpg"   width="200" height="300" alt="a picture of me" />
            </a>    
             <p>Click on it and youll go to my Facebook page</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade " id="menu2" style="padding:15px">
      <h3>My Businesses</h3>
      <p>other content</p>
    </div>
</div><!--tab content-->
</div><!--container-->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```